# LTE D2D multicast Communication

Tags: ns-3

I ave to build a topology where multiple nodes (4-5 UE) are connected via to an eNB and eNB is giving coverage in 4 different directions of the cellular network. or it can be said that:

coverage area of eNB is further divided into 4 sectors (or 4 different multicast groups )and above mentioned UE belongs to each MCs (multicast groups, which are 4). i.e; 4-5 UEs/MC group.

MC1 has 4-5 UEs
MC2 has 4-5 UEs
MC3 has 4-5 UEs
MC4 has 4-5 UEs

UEs have to communicate to eNB and it's going to be TCP/IP communication. Cellular network is going to send traffic data and UEs has to send back ack/NACK to eNB.

and in this Scenerio I have to calculate statistics of reliability.

There r only two frequencies which are being shared by diagonally opposite MCs. i.e; MC1 and MC3 are going to share same frequency while MC2 and MC4 are going to share another same frequency.

In return UEs of same MCs have to send back ACK/NACK in the same subframe of RB.

In ns-3 there are no such examples. How could I build the topology ?

Any kind of suggestions are highly appreciated. 
Please support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the community about how to build a non-trivial scenario from scratch.  You will probably get a better response if you can try to work it out yourself first and then ask more specific questions if you get stuck.  The ns-3-users Google Groups forum is probably better suited for this type of question, once you can refine your question.  Please note that in ns-3 there is neither D2D nor multicast support in the LTE module of the current release.